# Import CSV data in a rails app using collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, csv-import

I am trying to allow the importer to select a collection select option during import. Right now the importer works, how ever it does not select the model type during import.

My schema:

```
  create_table "hardwares", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "serialnumber"
    t.string "modelnumber"
    t.string "location"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "poc_id"
    t.integer "modeltype_id"
    t.index ["modeltype_id"], name: "index_hardwares_on_modeltype_id"
    t.index ["poc_id"], name: "index_hardwares_on_poc_id"
  end

  create_table "modeltypes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "mtype"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pocs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "facility"
    t.string "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

hardware.rb

```
class Hardware < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :serialnumber
  def self.import(file)
    if file == nil
    else
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Hardware.create row.to_hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Import Def in my hardwares controller:

```
def import
    Hardware.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to hardwares_url, notice: 'Hardware was successfully imported.'
end
```

CSV file

```
serialnumber,modelnumber,location,poc_id,modeltype_id
S123,M1,deployed,Joe,Dell
S456,M2,local,Shmoe,HP
```

When I run the importer it fills in Serial Number and ModelNumber and ignores location, poc_id, and modeltype_id. How can I use the drop down menus during import. Essentially I would like it to search the drop down for a match and select that as it imports.